# Why is the available capacity of an SLA battery and its cutoff voltage different for different discharge rates?

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

For example of this curve from [this](https://www.raiongroup.com/content/RG12350FP.pdf) datasheet of an SLA battery:
[image]

For 0.05C discharge rate over a 20 hour period, the usable capacity of the battery is 1C. Whereas, for 0.09C discharge rate over a period of about 10 hours, the usable capacity of the battery is 0.945C. And for 1C, the usable capacity of the battery is about 0.3C.

Comment: Most of the difference in cut-off voltage is easily explained by drop on inner resistance.

Comment: @greybeard Ah! I get it. What other factors can cause this difference?

Comment: I just took [Peukert's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert%27s_law) as a given. I'd expect to find explanations using that as a search term, from misleading to helpful.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to say how you're drawing your conclusions, including the figure in the datasheet that you're looking at, and the discharge rates that you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A higher current requires a greater density of ion flow in the electrolyte. As the battery chemistry gets close to being exhausted the ion concentration reduces, so the amount of current it can produce reduces. This is communicated as increased internal resistance and higher voltage drop, which reduces the usable capacity.

As for cutoff voltage, the manufacturer is just trying to make the battery look better. Looking at the curves we see that while there is generally higher voltage drop at high current, even at at 3C it is well past the knee at 10 V. At 2C and lower there is no significant advantage to going below 10 V.

The graph is perhaps a little misleading because when the battery appears to be 'flat' at 1C it actually still has capacity left that could be extracted at lower current, though of course if you *need* 1C this extra capacity isn't useful.

Comment: Essentially what you are saying is that at higher discharge rates, and when the battery is near exhaustion, the battery has a relatively high internal resistance and high voltage drop across its terminals. I still don't understand how this results in a reduced usable capacity of the battery.

Comment: To be 'usable' in most applications the battery has to put out voltage as well as current. If you try to draw more current than the ion transport can provide the current will be limited and voltage will drop to zero. This is not useful. At a lower current it's not limited so voltage stays up and is useful. There are some situations - eg. engine starter motor - where a large voltage drop is acceptable for a short period of time, but car batteries are rated by cranking amps, not capacity (taking all the charge out of a car battery will kill it!).